# Change Title case to Sentence case

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I have recently imported my products to my theme but now all the product descriptions are in  Title Case. How can I change it to normal sentence case? Can it be done in admin panel?

Comment: Could you tell me if the product descriptions are also in title case in the admin panel?

Comment: No, its all in sentence case when i use wysiwyg

Comment: Sounds like it's in the CSS. Could you provide me a link to a page I can view?

Comment: http://kidssociety.com.au/black-fox-lunch-bag.html

Comment: hm seems like its in your templates `view.phtml`. Can you check the code around the H1 tag in `app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`?

Comment: <div class="page-title product-title"> 
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>

Comment: Ahhh sorry I overlooked something. See my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capitalizing comes from the templates stylesheet.

Open up the file `skin/frontend/templatemela/MAG100206/css/styles.css` via FTP.
Locate the `body { ... }` part, it's at the top.

On line 37 you will find

```
text-transform:capitalize;
```

Please delete that, reload the page (with cntrl + shift + r) and the capitals should be gone